# Reset "maximal number of DLLs" does not work

Tags: r

My windows 7 Enterprise was automatically updated by itself. After the restart of the computer, an error (maximal number of DLLs reached… ) was shown in Rstudio (R-3.3.3) when the number of loaded DLLs reaches “100”. I reset the `"R_MAX_NUM_DLLs"` to 200, but still got the same error (LoadedDLLs=100).
Please see the message and information shown below. Did anyone meet this issue previously?

```
library(scde)
```

> Error in inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), …) :
>   unable to load shared object ‘C:/Program Files/R/R-3.3.3/library/mgcv/libs/x64/mgcv.dll’:
>   `maximal number of DLLs reached…
>   Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘scde’

```
Sys.getenv("R_MAX_NUM_DLLs", unset = NA)
```

[1] "200"

```
length(getLoadedDLLs())
```

[1] 100

Comment: Thank! Yes, it is an R issue. Fixed by updating R to the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix it by downlaoding Henrik Bengtsson's **R.utils** package (on CRAN) and then simply executing the following `R.utils::gcDLLs()`

Some more info describing it is here: [nabble thread about R.utils package](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Maximum-of-DLLs-reached-or-how-to-clean-up-after-yourself-td4724655.html)

Did not even require a restart :). Thanks Henrik!